# Group by question in SQL Server, migration from MySQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

Failed finding a solution to my problem, would love your help.

~~ Post has been edited to have only one question ~~-

Group by one query while selecting multiple columns.
In `MySQL` you can simply group by whatever you want, and it will still select all of them, so if for example I wanted to select the newest 100 transactions, grouped by Email (only get the last transaction of a single email)

In MySQL I would do that:

```sql
SELECT * FROM db.transactionlog
group by Email
order by TransactionLogId desc
LIMIT 100;
```

In `SQL Server` its not possible, googling a bit suggested to specify each column that I want to have with an aggregate as a hack, that couldn't cause a mix of values (mixing columns between the grouped rows)?

For example:

```sql
SELECT TOP(100)
   Email,
   MAX(ResultCode) as 'ResultCode',
   MAX(Amount) as 'Amount',
   MAX(TransactionLogId) as 'TransactionLogId'
  FROM [db].[dbo].[transactionlog]

  group by Email
  order by TransactionLogId desc
```

`TransactionLogId` is the `primarykey` which is identity , ordering by it to achieve the last inserted.
Just want to know that the `ResultCode` and `Amount` that I'll get doing such query will be of the last inserted row, and not the highest of the grouped rows or w/e.

~Edit~
Sample data -

row1:

```
Email : test@email.com
ResultCode : 100
Amount : 27
TransactionLogId : 1
```

row2:

```
Email: test@email.com
ResultCode:50
Amount: 10
TransactionLogId: 2
```

Using the sample data above, my goal is to get the row details of 
`TransactionLogId` = 2.
but what actual happens is that I get a mixed values of the two, as I do get transactionLogId = 2, but the resultcode and amount of the first row.
How do I avoid that?

Thanks.

Comment: `group by 'ProccessCount'` means Group By the **Literal String** `'ProccessCount'`. The delimit identifiers in T-SQL are brackets (`[]`), single quotes (`'`) are for literal strings. You also can't refer to a column by it's alias in the `GROUP BY` clause, you would have to repeat the expression; however considering that's a subquery that would be a bad idea.

Comment: I can answer the second question easiy - MySql is doing it wrong. 
The first question is a bit obscure.

In any case, you should strive to ask only one question in a post - and it seems to me that these two questions can and should be asked in two different posts.

Comment: I agree completely with @ZoharPeled on *"MySql is doing it wrong"*. It really bugs me that MySQL allows such awful syntax as `SELECT * FROM MyTable GROUP BY ArbitaryColumn`; what the aggregation you get in that query is about as clear as mud. (Of course, I also dislike that SQL Server hasn't deprecated the `{Expression} AS 'Literal String Alias'` functionality, only only deprecated `'Literal String Alias' = {Expression}`, which is why the OP ended up with `GROUP BY 'ProcessCount'`).

Comment: "Just want to know that the ResultCode and Amount that I'll get doing such query will be of the last inserted row"  Unless you have a column that keeps the order of rows as inserted to the table, this simply can't be done. Database table are unsorted sets - [there's no such things as a "natural order".](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/08/the-natural-order-misconception/)

Comment: @ZoharPeled
But if I uttilize TOP 100 and order by transactionLogId desc (which is the column that keeps the order of rows as inserted) that should work as I want to?
there is no risk of it mixing values of columns between the grouped rows cuz of the MAX use?
I'll edit my second question query to fit what I added here.

Comment: You seem to have multiple questions, so I'm closing this as too broad.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can I have a chance to split it into two different posts? O.O

5 minutes .

Comment: Removed the first question, will open another post with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first find out which is the latest transaction log by each email, then join back against the same table to retrieve the full record:

```
;WITH MaxTransactionByEmail AS
(
    SELECT
        Email,
        MAX(TransactionLogId) as LatestTransactionLogId
    FROM 
        [db].[dbo].[transactionlog]
    group by 
        Email
)
SELECT
    T.*
FROM
    [db].[dbo].[transactionlog] AS T
    INNER JOIN MaxTransactionByEmail AS M ON T.TransactionLogId = M.LatestTransactionLogId
```

You are currently getting mixed results because your aggregate functions like `MAX()` is considering all rows that correspond to a particular value of `Email`. So the `MAX()` value for the `Amount` column between values `10` and `27` is `27`, even if the transaction log id is lower.

Another solution is using a `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to get a row-ranking by each `Email`, then just picking the first row:

```
;WITH TransactionsRanking AS
(
    SELECT
        T.*,
        MostRecentTransactionLogRanking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY 
                T.Email                     -- Start a different ranking for each different value of Email
            ORDER BY 
                T.TransactionLogId DESC)    -- Order the rows by the TransactionLogID descending
    FROM 
        [db].[dbo].[transactionlog] AS T
)
SELECT
    T.*
FROM
    TransactionsRanking AS T
WHERE
    T.MostRecentTransactionLogRanking = 1
```

Comment: First solution seems exactly what I needed. are there any performance benefits of doing the second solution instead of the first?
Thanks EzLo!

Comment: On a table without indexes I doubt you'd find considerable differences. If you had an index on `Email` as first column and `TransactionLodId` is clustered then the first solution is likely to be faster. Even then, SQL Server might decide to switch to a different plan depending on statistics, so your best bet is to test both with an amount of rows you'd expect to have in a real scenario.